# Does my alternative proof of Bolzano-Weierstraß make sense, or am I missing something?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers, cauchy-sequences

I want to show that every bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ has a convergent subsequence.
Let $a_n$ be any bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Since $a_n$ is bounded, $\text{limsup}(a_n)$ exists, call it $k$. By lemma, for any $\epsilon > 0$, the set $\{n \;|\; \text{limsup}(a_n) - \epsilon < a_n < \text{limsup}(a_n) + \epsilon \}$ is infinite. If we let $\epsilon$ become arbitrarily small, and include only the $n$'s from our defined set into our subsequence, we have obtained a subsequence, that, by definition, converges to $k$. Hence, every bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: This can't work because you only use the fact that $a_n$ is bounded above. For example $-n$ has no convergent subsequences but is bounded above

Comment: Oh well the premise is that $a_{n}$ is bounded above and below. We're working with a sequence that is totally contained within an interval. Would my proof make sense in that context?

Comment: You never use that assumption though so it can't make the proof valid. And it isn't true that every bounded sequence has a subsequence which converges to its supremum so the result you get is false anyway.

Comment: Specifically the problem is that you assume that $\{n \;|\; \text{limsup}(a_n) - \epsilon < a_n < \text{limsup}(a_n) + \epsilon \}$ is infinite. In general this is not true.

Comment: That's a lemma that I was given in class, and is taken to be true for bounded sequences. How is it not true in general?

Comment: Wait I am an idiot. I thought you were using $\sup$ not $\limsup$. Your proof is in fact correct.

Comment: I think you guys are not making a distinction between sup and limsup? The limsup of $\frac{1}{n}$ would be 0, not 1, no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139391/discussion-between-jhon-mayday-and-fishbane).